# Blocking select on a div allows select around a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I have an HTML document. It needs to work across as many browsers as possible.

I block selecting on some items, specifically those contained in a div. That works, it doesn't get selected. But when you click **inside** that div and then drag the pointer **outside**, selecting continues to happen OUTSIDE of the div, and you see the blue selection box, etc.

I need that not to happen.

I need it so that:

- if you click outside of the box (starting outside the box) you can select/drag as normal, including around (but not in) the box. Frankly the behaviour I have here is fine.
- if you click inside of the box you cannot select or drag, even if you go outside of the box.

See example below - when you click inside the box and then move the mouse the contents of the box are not selected (in my production code the boxes don't even get highlighted) but everything between them does.

(Note that there may be one or more divs - in the example below I have 3).

I've tried a load of things - cancelling the mousedown of various elements, cancelling the selectstart of various elements AND the body (including in the capture phase rather than the bubble), etc. etc. It still happens.

I'm particularly confused that cancelling the selectstart on the body does not work (at least in Chrome, probably others). I have given the sample code I use for that (excluding the logic for catching if we started in the box).

I am sure this is possible - if you open youtube and try to click/hold on the position slider of the video, then move/drag outside the video box, nothing gets selected.

I'm probably missing something obvious - I'm tying myself in knots here - but can anyone help?

PS Yes I know the code's not great, it's a cut-down version of my full code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>
.Box
{
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;

    background-color: white;
    border-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="Box1" class="Box" unselectable="on" style="width:400px; height:100px;">Box1</div>
<br />
<div id="Box2" class="Box" unselectable="on" style="width:400px; height:100px;">Box2</div>
<br />
<div id="Box3" class="Box" unselectable="on" style="width:400px; height:100px;">Box3</div>
<br />

<script>

    this.blockSelect = function()
    {
        // for ie < 10
        var box1 = document.getElementById('Box1');
        var box2 = document.getElementById('Box2');
        var box3 = document.getElementById('Box3');
        box1.onselectstart = function() {
            return false;
        };
        box2.onselectstart = function() {
            return false;
        };
        box3.onselectstart = function() {
            return false;
        };
    }

    blockSelect();

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Capture cancelling:

```
this.cancelBubble = function(e)
{   // called from within an event, and passes that as e
    var evt = e ? e:window.event;
    if (evt.stopPropagation)    evt.stopPropagation();
    if (evt.cancelBubble!=null) evt.cancelBubble = true;
}

this.eventDocOnSelectStart = function(e)
{
    if (true)
    {
        cancelBubble(e);
        return false;
    }
};

document.body.addEventListener("selectstart", this.eventDocOnSelectStart, true);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `user-select: none;` for body?

Comment: I come with @RobinDorbell for the `user-select : none` on the whole body. It will then easier to allow only element you need to be selected by adding a class which enable selecting for example.

Comment: But I need __everything__ except those boxes selectable.

Comment: Frankly, this is just because I have a bar that shows where you are in the playback, and you can click/drag that bar to change your position (a la youtube). Right now, if you leave the box while dragging then suddenly it is selecting things on the page. But I don't want to break an entire type of page functionality (select / copy) for that. I __need__ the rest of the page to be selectable - but not when you are dragging the position bar.

Comment: How about adding the `user-select: none;` on body while mouse is down then?

Comment: Just tested it. Added a class when mouse goes down over the box, and remove it when mouse goes up over the document. Think it might need to be tweaked for other browsers to eg add the unselectable attribute, etc. (will look at it shortly, but my significant other is waiting....) but still - it's brilliant. And so simple. Could you create an answer so I can tick it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `user-select: none;` on `body` while mouse is hovering the box.

Comment: This works. Added a class when mouse goes down over the box, and remove it when mouse goes up over anywhere in the document. Think it might need to be tweaked for other browsers to eg add the unselectable attribute, etc. Many thanks.